# I sent eth from binance to friend tech base and it seems I make a mistake

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20

I haven't received the eth I sent from my binance to friend tech base please how do I recover it?

Comment: If the withdraw was processed binance should show you a transaction id. With that id you can look for the transaction. Transaction once they are confirmed it is unlikely to be reversed.

Comment: ANSWER: You can export your secret in friend.tech and import it into MetaMask or CoinbaseWallet and you should see your ETH there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recover them because you were supposed to send base chain eth and you might’ve sent the mainnet eth accidentally and there’s no way to recover. You should’ve read their warning first.